# Event on each Control Array in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub cbtns_ClickButtonArea(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles cbtn_a.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_b.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_c.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_d.ClickButtonArea
    Dim cbtn As CButtonLib.CButton() = {cbtn_a, cbtn_b, cbtn_c, cbtn_d}        

    For Each cb As CButtonLib.CButton In cbtn
        cb.Enabled = True
    Next        
End Sub
```

how to detect if what button did i clicked? i just want to disable the button i clicked or change it properties..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub cbtns_ClickButtonArea(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles cbtn_a.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_b.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_c.ClickButtonArea, cbtn_d.ClickButtonArea
    Dim cbtn As CButtonLib.CButton() = {cbtn_a, cbtn_b, cbtn_c, cbtn_d}        
    Dim clickedBtn As CButtonLib.CButton = DirectCast(sender, CButtonLib.CButton)

    For Each cb As CButtonLib.CButton In cbtn
        If cb Is clickedBtn Then
            cb.Enabled = False
        Else
            cb.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System,Windows.Forms.Button' and 'Object'.

Comment: that's the error you got? I changed the cast to `CButtonLib.CButton`, try that

Comment: still getting this error.. Error Operator '=' is not defined for types 'CButtonLib.CButton' and 'CButtonLib.CButton'.

Comment: anyway, i got this customized button here.. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/CButton.aspx

Comment: ok, I fixed the code. Must use `Is` to compare these 2 objects not `=`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CType(Sender, Button).Enabled = False
```

to disable the button that was clicked.

Comment: when i put event on the CButton.. this line from CButton got highlighted and warnings.. Private Sub CButton_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        If MouseDrawState = eMouseDrawState.Down Then RaiseEvent ClickButtonArea(Me, e)
        MouseDrawState = eMouseDrawState.Up
        Me.Invalidate(Rectangle.Round(ButtonArea))
    End Sub